# Is there any way to wrap a dependency class with a static class?

Tags: dependency-injection, static-classes

[image]

This image defines how my application is designed, where controller calls a business method through its interface and business method calls repository through repository interface.
My question is how do a create a Static class (e.g-utility cla) in my Business Project which call a repository and gets the result.

Comment: I think the question that we may need an answer to is why do you need your class to be static?

Comment: Since the class is a utility class so preferably to be a static one. If not then again need to pass interface object in the utility class constructor to avoid error due to dependency injection.

Comment: If your utility class requires access to the items that you are otherwise injecting as a dependency then that class should likely not be static and instead be used as an injected dependency where needed.

Comment: if you really need a static utility class than you have to use Service Location and not Dependency Injection. This is something not reccomended beacuse your static methods can become very hard to test. You can even create a utility class without static methods and register it in your DI container and use it as dependency where you need it. I would use the last approach.